# checkbox not updating flutter bloc

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, flutter-test, bloc

I want to make a coffee machine app 
[image]
I want to update a checkbox in flutter bloc package,
I use bloc to state management 
I try searching on the web but I don't have a good answer to this problem 
tips to help me, my files are named `AppCubit` is a bloc file and `AppState` is states and `ChangeCheckBox` and the screen `MainModule`

`AppCubit` is cubit class

```
class AppCubit extends Cubit<AppState> {
  AppCubit() : super(AppInitial());
  // value in 
  bool isWithCreamChecked = false;
  static AppCubit get(BuildContext context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  // this is a function for changing the value of the checkbox
  void checkBox({bool? value, bool? changeValue}) {
    changeValue = value!;
    emit(ChangeCheckBox(value,changeValue));
  }
}
```

`AppState` all states in the app

```
abstract class AppState {}

class AppInitial extends AppState {}

// checkbox states
class ChangeCheckBox extends AppState {
  bool value;
  bool changeValue;
  ChangeCheckBox(this.value,this.changeValue);
}
```

in `MainModule`

```
 Checkbox(
 value: AppCubit.get(context).isWithCreamChecked,
 onChanged: (bool? value) {
   AppCubit.get(context).isWithCreamChecked = value!;
 },
),
const Text('adding Cream to coffee, price is 20')

Checkbox(
 value: AppCubit.get(context).isWithCreamChecked,
 onChanged: (bool? value) {
  AppCubit.get(context).checkBox(
  value: value!,
  changeValue:AppCubit.get(context).isWithCreamChecked
  );
 },
),
const Text('adding cream  to coffee, price is 10')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are putting ! with value two times (`value!`). One before sending it to checkbox function here.

```
AppCubit.get(context).checkBox(
  value: value!,
  changeValue:AppCubit.get(context).isWithCreamChecked
);
```

Then again when you are setting the checkbox inside the cubit.

```
void checkBox({bool? value, bool? changeValue}) {
    changeValue = value!;
    emit(ChangeCheckBox(value,changeValue));
}
```

This will leads to making it the same value as you got initially.

Just do it once to change values. Also put `!` before the value for changing the value before setting it like `changeValue = !value`